# tcpreplay, different packet number with pcap file

Tags: wireshark, pcap, tcpreplay

I have a **pcap** file, captured with Wireshark,with **2690** packets
I use **tcpreplay** to replay it on an interface,
 but the problem is that the number of Attempted packets in tcpreplay is different(less) with  number of packets showing in wireshark

```
#tcpreplay -i eth1 test.pcap
 sending out eth1
 processing file: /tmp/reloadtest4.pcap
 Actual: 1826 packets (1634597 bytes) sent in 58.06 seconds.
 Rated: 28153.6 bps, 0.21 Mbps, 31.45 pps
 Statistics for network device: eth1
    Attempted packets:         1826
    Successful packets:        1826
    Failed packets:            0
    Retried packets (ENOBUFS): 0
    Retried packets (EAGAIN):  0
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug in Tcpreplay, or it may be an issue with your capture. I suggest logging the issue [here](https://github.com/appneta/tcpreplay/issues%20%22here%22.). Include the output of **tcpreplay -V**. Also rename the packet capture with a suffix of **.txt** and you will be able to upload it to the issue.